# ¿Como cambiar el formato utcnow() a un formato manipulable?

Tags: python

Hola amigos ¿como puedo cambiar el formato utcnow de datetime a un formato donde yo pueda manipular la fecha de forma arbitraria?
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.utcnow()
print(date)
```

Comment: define la manera en la que quieres cambiar la fecha, quieres sumarle días, horas ...? Añade un ejemplo de como manipularías la fecha por favor